# Unable to login through GUI as a user but I am able to login via terminal

Tags: 13.04, ssh, login, gui, authentication

I am unable to login through GUI as a user but I am able to login via terminal.

This occurred after I installed *2 steps authenticator* of Google using `apt-get install` command. I followed these steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator`
2. Edited `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and add the following line to the file:

   ```
   auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
   ```
3. Edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and changed `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` to `yes`
4. I restarted the *ssh* service.

   ```
   root@george:~# ls -l /home/george/.Xauthority  
   -rw------- 1 root root 125 Jan 31 19:35 /home/george/.Xauthority
   ```

Comment: log-in via terminal & type `ls -l /home/user/.Xauthority`.. change it to your username instead of **user**. Please post the output of that line by [**editing**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/416232/edit) your question.

Answer (score 3):

Well, by the look of your output for `ls -l /home/user/.Xauthority` shows that the file is owned by **root** where it is supposed to be **user**. In your case, it should be `george`. Moving the file or giving permission to its origin user would fix if I'm not mistaken. Anyhow, please follow below steps by logging in via terminal;

- Log in as the user (as **goerge**) & change to the user's home directory

```
cd /home/user                 # in your case, its /home/george
```

or even a single `cd ~` command will take you directly to the home folder of the user.

- I do not recommend deleting or changing ownership at first, so let us move it by backing-up

```
sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak
```

- And then reboot your system.

```
sudo reboot
```

**P.S.:** There are instance where this may work to get your problem fixed or may not. Since you're not deleting the original `.Xauthority` file it won't be a harm.

**Source:** [Lost gui after ending xorg process](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1890457)

Comment: Azker Mohamed its worked for me thank you very much

Comment: @user237793 I'm glad it helped you. And, please accept it as answer if it helped you. This will also reduce the question queue. :)